# Prevent back button in Chrome/Edge/IE to reset select value?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I’m working on a filter that return hits based on values in different select boxes. When you click back in Firefox (54) the values are still present. But in Chrome/Edge/IE the select boxes are reset to blank/default value.

Is there any way to prevent and store the selected values somehow? Mabye with local storage?

Answer (score 0):

What about using cookies?

You could probably just store data in a cookie and clear it out when you need it.

Edit: Local storage isn't available on all browsers, that's why I am recommending cookie over it

Comment: Ok, that could be an option. Is there any good practice for setting this type of cookie? It should expire quite quick I imagine?

Comment: It might as well just be a session cookie which could be erased manually if unneeded or expire when you close the browser. That's just my opinion

Comment: There really isn't a browser you should be supporting that lacks support for localStorage - http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage